# Does this ３度まで refer to quantity or frequency?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180125/k10011302761000.html

The sentence in question:
熊野那智大社によりますと、２５日午前７時の滝の周辺の気温は氷点下３度まで下がったということです。

My attempt at tramslation:
"When it becomes evening at 熊野那智大社, concerning the atmosphere of the surroundings of the waterfall at 7a.m on the 25th day (of the month), it came down below freezing 3 times."

My translation is quite clumsy, but thats also because I struggled to resolve this huge nominal phrase ２５日午前７時の滝の周辺の気温. Im also not sure wether grammatically ５日午前７時 should be parsed as an adverb or part of the attribute 滝の周辺 to 気温.
I mainly want to know if ３度まで should be interpreted as "three times" like in "did X 3 times" or "was three times X" here. Id also like to know wether it can actually be interpreted in both ways or just in one of the two.

Comment: As an aside, do you understand [依りますと](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AB%E4%BE%9D%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8) correctly?

Comment: After user27280's answer, I think so :=) I know によると, but I didnt know that it can take a polite form. ^^ Now I know better, hopefully :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

度 in this instance means 'degrees' （何℃）. 氷点 is the 'freezing point' and 下 is 'below'. 氷点下 means sub-zero or below-freezing. 氷点下3度 is 3° below.

> 熊野那智大社によりますと、According to Kumano Nachi Taisha,
>
> ２５日午前７時の滝の周辺の気温は the air temperature around the waterfall on the 25th
>   at 7:00 am
>
> 氷点下３度まで下がったということです。dropped down to 3 degrees below the freezing point.